# Query JSON in Mongodb without full path

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to query JSON in MongoDb without the full path of the objects you're querying...

IE pretend you have some arbitrarily nested JSON object:

//pretend there is 5 json objects nested within eachother here:

```
producer: {
    company: 'ABC123',
    address: '123 Street'
}
```

I want to be able to do something like db.table.find("address": "123 street") and get back the entire json block. I won't know the entire path like X.Y.Z.producer.address : 123 street, so I'd like to just be able to query on the attribute I want and get back all the json objects that contain that attribute.

Comment: and if it isn't possible, is there a better db to use for this use case?

Comment: One of the options is to setup the document model that is more plain and better matching your data access pattern. So if this is the address which you need to search for, you can make it top level document, and have a reference to it in other documents. You'll have to do two queries in such a case: search for address and then get all the model instances which have that address.

Comment: i have no control over the json structure at the company I work for. Also, we want the user of our service to abitrarily be able to type in queries, like,  "give me all rows where the JSON contains attribute Y which is set to value Z and is a child of attribute X. (X.Y = Z)